# Sharing data between controllers AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to sent an array filled with objects from controller 1 to controller 2. But all I get in controller 2 is an empty array. The only way I get a filled one is when I create a static array in my service.

My service

```
app.service('myData', function () {
this.myData = [];

this.addData = function(data) {
    this.myData.push(data);
}
this.getData = function() {
    return this.myData;
}});
```

controller 1 which sets the data

```
app.controller('controller1',['$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData) {
    $scope.addData = function(index, name) {
        myData.addData({index: index, name: name});
    }}]);
```

Controller 2 looks like this

```
app.controller('controller2',['$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData) {

$scope.myData = myData.getData();
$scope.$watch('myData.getData()', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
console.log($scope.myData);}]);
```

When I was searching for an answer I found alot of questions almost similar to mine. The only difference was that I fill my service from my controller instead of creating a static service.

Both my console.logs return an empty array. Why is this?

Comment: you need to use the root scope or one of the communicartion mechanism like the broadcast or events

Comment: your watch seems a little strange to me. try this `function(){ return myData.getData() }` instead of `data.getData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$watch` expression should be a function ([see the docs for `$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)). Giving `$watch` a string tells Angular to inspect a property on the `$scope`. As well as this, you have mistakenly referenced your `myData` service as 'data' in the string `'data.getData()'`.

1) Watch the result of `myData#getData`:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return myData.getData();
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

2) Watch the reference to the `myData` service's internal array on `$scope`:

```
$scope.myData = myData.getData();
$scope.$watch('myData', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you call the `addData` from the first controller for example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/08cv5nx7/)

```
.controller('tourCtrl', ['$scope', 'myData', function ($scope, myData) {
    $scope.addData = function (index, name) {
        myData.addData({
            index: index,
            name: name
        });
    }
    $scope.addData('hello', 'world');
}])
.controller('controller2', ['$scope', 'myData', function ($scope, myData) {

    $scope.myData = myData.getData();
    $scope.$watch('myData', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    console.log($scope.myData);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest that you use something like pubsub mechanism. you can't know when will data appear. and watching a function is an expensive operation. You can build a PubSub mechanism on your service.

A controller could register for an event and another could publish that event. so with minimum resources you could achieve what you want.

here is a sample

```
app.factory('pubSubService', [function() {
var pubSubAPI = {};
var hooks = [];

pubSubAPI.publishEvent = function(message) {
    for (var i = 0; i < hooks.length; i++) {
        hooks[i](message);
    }
};

pubSubAPI.subscribeEvent = function(eventFunction) {

    hooks.push(eventFunction);
};

return pubSubAPI;
}]);
```

Comment: [This type of functionality is already available in Angular](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/).

Comment: yes but this type of functionality on angularjs is for scopes. unless you want to use rootScope - which i am always trying to avoid. you cant use angular functionality on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach would be to use the Observer Pattern, saves having to use the `$watch`at all:

```
app.service('myData', function () {
    this.myData = [];
    var observers = [];
    var self = this;

    this.addObserver = function (callback) {
        observers.push(callback);
    };

    var notifyObservers = function () {
        angular.forEach(observers, function (callback) {
            callback(self.myData);
        });
    };


    this.addData = function (data) {
        this.myData.push(data);
        notifyObservers();

    }
});


app.controller('controller2', ['$scope', 'myData', function ($scope, myData) {

    myData.registerObserverCallback(function (data) {
        $scope.myData = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```